# How to compare DateTimeField with timezone.now()

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python/django and I have an Events app where users can see upcoming events of an organization but I don't know how to show only future events and disregard events from the past.

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = RichTextField()
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(NewUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
class ShowEventsListPageView(ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'registration/user_events.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.kwargs['pk']
        return Event.objects.filter(author=user).annotate(Event.end_date > timezone.now()).order_by('-start_date')
```

This code is returning **'>' not supported between instances of 'DeferredAttribute' and 'datetime.datetime'**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [greater than (gt)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#gt) lookup is used to filter a queryset where a field is greater than a value

```
Event.objects.filter(
    author=user,
    end_date__gt=timezone.now()
).order_by('-start_date')
```